# perl a user supplied sub, always returns the text, not the eval

Tags: perl, eval, anonymous-function

I am a perl newb.

Unfortunately, `eval` doesn't work the way I'm expecting

My mock example:

```
my $filter = 'return false;';
my $filterFunc = sub{ eval{ $filter } } ;
while (my $entry = readNextEntry()){
    print "Eval:".$filterFunc->( $entry )."\n";
}
```

When I run this, I get the literal `"return false;"` being returned from every pass (rather than the function getting evaluated). I've tried a couple of variations, but I'm not hitting the magic combination.

A note on security implications:

As I am the user, I don't have security concerns about what the passed in code does.

My intent is to pull in multiple sources and filter out stuff based on parameters, since I don't know what parameters are going to be useful, I thought I could pass in some text, `eval` the text into an anonymous function, and run the function for each record (a filter function). As I am the user, I don't have security concerns about what the passed in code does.

Comment: While you're right that your approach will work, and I understand that you don't think you should be too concerned about the `eval`, I will still say that it would be safer to implement different kinds of filters and call them with arguments when needed. A dispatch table would be handy here. Don't even trust yourself as a user.

Comment: I'm definitely game for a totally different solution. I am trying to implement a *very* generic query utility. The point to that eval is it should resolve to a function that always returns true/false and never does anything else. In the short term, apparently I just misread how eval works.

Comment: What are you querying? If the data is in any way record based, why not load it into a relational database and use SQL? I hear that's good at querying.

Comment: There are a few reasons: volume is one of them. A streaming database would be an even better choice, but is not an option. Ergo... hand crafted aggregate > filter > map > reduce

Comment: To expand on my response (post holiday): I am reading from a continuous stream, and want to use this to decide what to even bother writing to a more permanent store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do *string `eval`*, not *block `eval`*.

```
my $filterFunc = sub{ eval{ $filter } } ;
```

The `eval BLOCK` is like a `try`/`catch` mechanism. It does not evaluate arbitrary code. It catches errors in the code inside the block. What you want is string `eval`.

```
my $filterFunc = sub{ eval $filter };
```

Here's an example implementation of what I think you are trying to do:

```
$ perl -E 'my $filter = sub { my $f = shift; eval $ARGV[0]; }; for ( 1 .. 10 ) { say $_ if $filter->($_) }' '$f % 2'
1
3
5
7
9
```

However, there is no `false` in Perl. That's not a keyword. Unless you have  `sub false` somewhere, this might give you a syntax error, depending on if you have `use strict` or not.

You should [read up on `eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).

---

If all you want is a `$filterFunc` that returns something *false*, use `0` instead. Note that the literal string `"return false;"` is *true* in Perl.

Comment: "return false" was exactly the next problem I hit